# Span and Linear Dependence Question with Thm

Tags: linear-algebra

There is a theorem I am reading and it states that

> if $x_{k}$ in $X=\left \{ x_{1}, x_{2}, ..., x_{k} \right \}$ is linearly dependent on $\left \{ x_{1}, x_{2}, ..., x_{k-1} \right \}$, then $\hbox{span } (X)=\hbox{span }(X-\left \{ x_{k}\right \})$.

It then starts the proof by saying, "Every vector in $X$ can be expressed as a linear combination in $X-\left \{ x_{k}\right \}$."

---

Why can every vector in $X$ be expressed as this linear combination? I thought that since X is dependent that there exists a vector in X that can be expressed as this linear combination. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Since $x_k$ is linearly **dependent** on $\{x_1,\ldots,x_{k-1}\}$, we have that $x_k$ is a linear combination of $x_1,\ldots,x_{k-1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hypothesis part of the theorem is assuming a bit more than just the linear dependence of the set $X$. In addition the theorem requires $x_k$ to depend on the other elements of $X$. It's this fact that lets us know we can represent $x_k$ as such a linear combination. To see that the rest of the $x_i$ have a representation as a linear combination of elements in $X-\{ x_k\}$, we just take the trivial combination $x_i=x_i$.

Answer (score 1):

For $i=1,\cdots, k-1$, $x_i$ is obviously a linear combination of $\{x_1,\cdots,x_{k-1}\}$. But $x_k$ is also a linear combination of $x_1,\cdots,x_{k-1}$ by the assumption; this is what the "if..." part means.

Comment: So every $x_{k}$ (i.e. k= 1, 2) can be represented and not just one?

Comment: $k$ is a fixed number. What you want to say is that $x_i$ ($i=1,\cdots,k-1$) is obviously a linear combination of $x_1,\cdots,x_{k-1}$.